# Python venv gets created in Python311 Programm Folder instead of cwd

Tags: python, path, virtualenv

So, I have both Python3.12 and Python3.11.6 installed on my computer.
I've had problems with my Path after I reinstalled 3.11.6, therefore decided to add C:\PATHShortcuts to my PATH, with shortcuts (python3.11 and python3.12) that point to the respective User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python31x\ folders.
This worked great.

But now, when I hit in the cmd prompt (I'm on Windows) `python3.11 -m venv venv --prompt some_prompt` , the venv folder gets created not in my current working directory but in  path\to\Python31x\  . So I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Is this a behaviour change between versions of Python or just because the Python binaries are installed into a writable directory? What value is returned if you run `from os.path import abspath` and then `abspath('venv')`?  Can you detour the problem by typing "python3.11 -m venv <full path>"?